# After deleting the wrong content, it will still be marked in red until compiled again

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, vscode-tasks

There is something wrong with my vscode.
When a compilation error occurred, I corrected the error, but the correction will not be reflected in the red mark untill compiled again.
g++ version 13.1.0

Here are screenshots of the error.
An error occurred.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epfox.png)
it doesn't disappear evenif i delete it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w09sP.png)

Here's my tasks' configuration.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai7DI.png)

I want the red tilde to disappear immediately when my code has no errors instead of remaining there until the next compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the effect of `"problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]`. Ditch it.

Simply having an intellisense plugin installed (either the stock `C/C++` plugin, or `Clangd`, depending on your preference) should give you squiggles updating in real time.

Comment: I just found out I have installed `c/c++` plugin. ["$gcc"] --- the para of "problemMatcher" seems to be generated by this plugin because I checked the para originally provided by  "problemMatcher" on the official website and did not see "[$gcc]".     The question seems to become what should I do under the premise of using this plugin? Is there any configurable option that I haven’t found?

Comment: @maisado You simply remove this line. Does it work if you do it? You might need to do some additional configuration if you see false positive errors.

Comment: After I removed it, the red tilde disappeared completely, and this error was only reported in the console after compilation. I think it may be related to this being a compilation error, because other syntax errors can add red tilde normally. I now feel that the '$gcc' para is not as wrong as I imagined. The failure of the red tilde to disappear in time should be related to this special error type. If I want to achieve my requirements, maybe I need to continue to learn related compilation error types in depth. Thank you very much. If you have any other suggestions for me, please let me know.

Comment: @maisado *"this being a compilation error, because other syntax errors can add red tilde normally"* What other errors could there be, except compilation ones? I'm not too familiar with the stock C/C++ extension, it certainly can display the squiggles, but I'm not sure if it requires any configuration to do so (I thought not?). Clangd certainly displays them out of the box.

Comment: The compilation errors I refer to are errors that will only be discovered and marked after compilation. Errors other than compilation errors include missing semicolons, unpaired brackets, etc, which will be marked during the process of writing code. My definition of the error type is not precise, just to differentiate between compiling or not.

Comment: @maisado At least from my experience with Clangd, it highlights most of the errors, except for linker errors and errors in complex templates, both of which would be hard to diagnose.

Comment: My compiler can mark errors other than compilation errors normally, but when a compilation error occurs, after I modify or delete the error code, it is still marked red in the blank space, which is the problem i wanna solve. I want these red squiggly lines to disappear immediately after I correct the code, instead of appearing in other correct places. I guess vscode may have relevant configurations that can be modified. I will check it out later. I will also consider using clangd, hoping it can solve my obsessive-compulsive disorder.

Comment: Okay, I will consider using the powerful clangd, thanks veryyyy much !